# Listening for events

Tags: iphone, cocoa

i wish to PUSH an XML File from a windows PC to the iPad,
how and what should i do so that the app can "listen" for events like that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [Local and Push Notification Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/NetworkingInternet/Conceptual/RemoteNotificationsPG/Introduction/Introduction.html).

You can only use push notifications to play alerts, display a message, or badge the application icon.

Anything more, and you have to take the client/server approach where the the apps must be running on both ends. A mix is usually best. Push a notification of something, which in turn can fire up the client, which in turn can download the latest chunk if structured information in XML (or whatever) form.